# Override a template method in scaffolded controllers

Tags: grails, controller, scaffold

I have a Grails project where I use heavily customized scaffolding templates to add a `beforeUpdate` template method to `update` so that I can easily customize scaffolded `Controller`'s without having to generate and then edit each controller separately.

Unfortunately this doesn't work and only `beforeUpdate` from scaffolding gets called.
I suspect it has to do with the code generation used by Groovy to inject the scaffolding code into the actual `Controller`, but I can't find any confirmation.

What I'm asking is either a solution to the problem or an explanation for why it doesn't work.

Here is the scaffolding code:

```
def beforeUpdate = {
    println "beforeUpdate from scaffold"
}

def update() {
    // call before update hook
    beforeUpdate()

    def ${propertyName} = ${className}.get(params.id)
    if (!${propertyName}) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: '${domainClass.propertyName}.label', default: '${className}'), params.id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }
    [...]
```

and the scaffolded controller code (which is not called, while I believe it should):

```
class CalendarController {
    static scaffold = Calendar

    def beforeUpdate = {
            println "beforeUpdate from controller"
    }
}
```

I have already tried *grails clean* ;-)

**UPDATE**

I have eventually realized that this is simply impossibile due to how the Grails scaffolding is designed. Closing.

Comment: To "close" this question, you should add your own answer and then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have eventually realized that this is simply impossibile due to how the Grails scaffolding is designed: by dynamically copying/creating methods into the scaffolded controllers and not using inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

You have a similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16332787/592139) - essentially the way scaffolding works the scaffolding template generates a separate class which the "real" controller delegates to.  So if you want the generated controller to call methods on the real controller you can't use `this`, you need to get a reference to the real controller object.

To cut a long story short, use

```
GrailsWebUtil.getControllerFromRequest(request).beforeUpdate()
```

instead of just

```
beforeUpdate()
```

---

```
def update() {
    // call before update hook
    def realController = GrailsWebUtil.getControllerFromRequest(request)
    if(realController.hasProperty('beforeUpdate') &&
         realController.beforeUpdate instanceof Closure) {
      realController.beforeUpdate()
    } else {
      this.beforeUpdate()
    }

    def ${propertyName} = ${className}.get(params.id)
    if (!${propertyName}) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: '${domainClass.propertyName}.label', default: '${className}'), params.id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }
    [...]
```